# Transform lowpass filter to highpass filter, what happened to unit sample response and difference equation?

Tags: filters, discrete-signals, signal-analysis, electrical-signal

I know that multiple a lowpass filter signal by $(-1)^n$ can transform it to a highpass filter.
$$
s_{hp}[n]=(-1)^n s_{lp}[n]
$$

But exactly what happened to the unit sample response and difference equation? Assume that the original lowpass filter signal has a difference equation. Can someone explain to me?? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a demonstration that confirms what @Hilmar said:

We recall the initial relationship:
\begin{equation}
s_{hp}[n]=(−1)^ns_{lp}[n]
\end{equation}

Let us calculate its discrete Fourier transform:

\begin{equation}
DFT\{s_{hp}[n]\}=S_{hp}[k]=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\{(−1)^ns_{lp}[n]\}e^{-j2\pi \frac{nk}{N}}
\end{equation}

But $(-1)^n$ is also equal to $e^{j\pi n}$, so:
\begin{equation}
S_{hp}[k]=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\{(e^{j\pi n})s_{lp}[n]\}e^{-j2\pi \frac{nk}{N}}\\
         =\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}s_{lp}[n]e^{j\pi n}e^{-j2\pi \frac{nk}{N}}\\
=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}s_{lp}[n]e^{j2\pi \frac{n}{N}(k-\frac{N}{2})}
\end{equation}

And so with a change of variable, we get:

\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}s_{lp}[n]e^{-j2\pi n\frac{k'}{N}}=S_{hp}[k']=S_{hp}[k-N/2]
\end{equation}

As a conclusion, we have the properties stated by @himar:

> What happens here is that SHIFT your signal frequency spectrum by half the sample rate
> Due to the periodicity of the spectrum, this looks like the spectrum has been mirrored at fs/4 (at least for real valued signals), i.e. DC become Nyquist, Nyquist becomes DC.

Answer (score 0):

> I know that multiple a lowpass filter signal by (−1)n can transform it to a highpass filter.

Depends a bit what you mean by that. If you assume that this will turn 1 kHz lowpass signal into a 1kHz high pass signal, your assumption is plain wrong. What happens here is that SHIFT your signal frequency spectrum by half the sample rate, $f_s$. Due to the periodicity of the spectrum, this looks like the spectrum has been mirrored at $fs_/4$ (at least for real valued signals), i.e. DC become Nyquist, Nyquist becomes DC.

So this operation flips the entire signal spectrum, regardless of whether it's been high-pass, low-pass, pink, white, etc.

Loosely speaking, if you have signal that's been low passed and you flip it, the spectrum may look a bit like that of a high passed signal, but it's completely different operation than filtering the original signal with a complimentary high pass.

> But exactly what happened to the unit sample response and difference equation? Assume that the original lowpass filter signal has a difference equation.

This is NOT an LTI operation, so difference equations and unit sample response do not apply here. Specifically, it's time variant.